# Rewriting in .htaccess with forward slashes

Tags: php, .htaccess

here is what I need.  I have the url pearlsquirrel.com/profilecomments.php?u=eggo.
eggo being my username and the part of the dynamic url that changes.  I would like to rewrite the url to say pearlsquirrel.com/eggo/comments, using .htaccess.

Here is what I have so far:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profilecomments.php?u=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profilecomments.php?u=$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.pearlsquirrel\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://pearlsquirrel.com/$1/comments [L,R=301]
```

but I just can not get it to work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Why cant you just make the php script redirect there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/comments$ profilecomments.php?u=$1 [L]
```

**NOTE**

If you've used relative paths for your images, stylesheets etc. you need to change those into absolute paths or relative paths using the servers root folder as base in order to get your site to display properly.

For example, it will think that `images/image.png` is `/eggo/comments/images/image.png`

But, if you instead add a preceding slash `/images/image.png`  your file paths will always start from the servers root folder and your site won't get messed up when you're rewriting your URL's.

Comment: that seems to work but for some reason no images render properly when I use this method.  http://pearlsquirrel.com/eggo/comments

Comment: @Eggo - That's because you've used relative paths for your images and stylesheets etc using your file's folder as base. (e.g. src="images/image.png") In order to get the included files and images to work you have to change to the absolute path or relative to the servers root folder (e.g. src="/images/image.png")

Answer (score 0):

Your first rule, overrides all the rest.
What you are describing (if I understood correctly), you need to handle /user/comments by profilecomments.php?u=user

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/comments profilecomments.php?u=$1 [L]
```

this should do it.